# Android Fragment with maps v2 render error

Tags: android, android-layout, opengl-es, google-maps-api-2

I have a full screen map with components over it.

When I click over menu button, A RelativeLayout that its also Full screen become visible.

Here comes my problem, instead of paint this layout correctly, its only appears over other components (other buttons and image) in the screen, but in area where only have map, map continues.

If I power off screen and open again, then Layout its painted correctly.

I try to capture with DDMS, but DDMS shows me the correct screen, the problem appears 4.0.4 and 2.3.6

I think problem comes because new maps use opengl. There is some code that I need to call after make my layout visible to change render of the map?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with a raw MapView and whenever I need to show another whole screen view I set the mapview visibility gone.